# How to extract all JSON values into an Excel file

Tags: python, json, excel

I have a **JSON** file which I want to **extract all value in the JSON into Excel.**

Each value (from JSON) = 1 column (in Excel).

I don't want to extract it again in Excel. Need final result from Python. But I don't know how to code on this part

Comment: What does the file look like? A flat structure fits easily in a tabular format like Excel. Nested objects will need to be flattened one way or another

Comment: The `json` module will let you turn a JSON file into a Python `dict`. As a second step you can then write that out as a `.csv`. But that step depends on the structure of the data, so you have to code it. There is no general solution, and if the JSON file contains nested or structured data, it is up to you to decide how to flatten it into rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

You may use Pandas and openpyxl:

First install it `pip install pandas openpyxl`, and then:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_json = pd.read_json(‘your_input_file.json’)
df_json.to_excel(‘your_output_file.xlsx’)
```

Take a look: https://www.marsja.se/how-to-convert-json-to-excel-python-pandas/

Comment: i try this but the value in json wasn't extracted . any suggestion

Comment: Could you please share how you tried it? You need to point both files to the actual location they're at.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do it with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df_json = pd.read_json(‘DATAFILE.json’)
df_json.to_excel(‘DATAFILE.xlsx’)
```

or:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('./SimData/save_to_excel.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel('./SimData/exported_json_data.xlsx')
```

Comment: the rseult is in excel file but the result wasan't extract . still in '{'